# Compacting a simple function

Tags: python-2.7

As I struggle with anonymous functions,
how would I be able to make the below code info a single line?

```
list1 = []
for i in range(some_number):
    list1.append(i * 100 + 50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
list1 = [i*100 + 50 for i in range(some_number)]
```

This runs as:

```
>>> list1 = [i*100 + 50 for i in range(10)]
>>> list1
[50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950]
>>>
```

Which is the same as:

```
>>> list1 = []
>>> for i in range(10):
...     list1.append(i*100 + 50)
... 
>>> list1
[50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950]
>>>
```

Comment: Damn, I was so close! Thank you!

Comment: @user2684432 If this answer helped you, would you mind accepting it and/or +1-ing it? Thanks :)